can't use data from ./stores via pinia on nuxt 3 project | Cannot read properties of undefined
When i using my project on local machine via "npm run dev", everything is going well. But as soon as i upload the project to the server, an error appears.
I have a button, which start render basket-supplies, an errors occurs when i click him.
On local machine everything is fine(log in browser and IDE). So at server(vercel) i got mistake in dev-console when i click on button:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'cartStore')
    at y (KV5dX6I7.js:1:9500)
    at onClick (KV5dX6I7.js:1:15949)
    at Zn (NWK0i2J7.js:14:38)
    at nt (NWK0i2J7.js:14:108)
    at HTMLButtonElement.n (NWK0i2J7.js:19:7629)

button:
                    <UiButton :variant="cartStore.isInCart(card.id) ? 'success' : 'action'"
                      @click="handleAddToCart(card.id, card.selectedRate)" class="mt-auto">
                        {{ cartStore.isInCart(card.id) ? 'В корзине' : 'В корзину' }}
                        <svg-icon v-if="cartStore.isInCart(card.id)" name="check-success" width="16" height="16" />
                    </UiButton>

function:
function handleAddToCart(cardId, selectedRate) {
    if (!selectedRate) {
        alert('Пожалуйста, выберите тарифный план.');
        return;
    }
    this.cartStore.addItem(cardId, selectedRate.id);
}

environment properties:
import { useCartStore } from '@/stores/cart';
import { onMounted } from 'vue';

import cardsData from '~/src/data/cards-data.json';
import ratesData from '~/src/data/rates-data.json';


onMounted(async () => {
    await Promise.all([
        cartStore.setCardsData(cardsData),
        cartStore.setRatesData(ratesData)
    ]);
});


const selectedRate = ref('');

Also pinia file cart.js:
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useCartStore = defineStore('cart', {
  state: () => ({
    cartItems: {}, // Объект вида { id: { count, rateId } }
    cardsData: [],
    ratesData: [],
  }),
actions: {
    addItem(id, rateId) {
      if (this.cartItems[id]) {
        this.cartItems[id].count++
      } else {
        this.cartItems[id] = { count: 1, rateId }
      }
    },
  },

The code is presented partially, if necessary I will send the whole or the necessary part.
logged data transfer:
function handleAddToCart(cardId, selectedRate) {
    // console.log('cartStore:', cartStore);
    console.log('cardId:', cardId);
    console.log('selectedRate:', selectedRate);
    if (!selectedRate) {
        alert('Пожалуйста, выберите тарифный план.');
        return;
    }
    this.cartStore.addItem(cardId, selectedRate.id);
}

console.log('cartStore is', cartStore ? 'available' : 'undefined');

failed to catch logs on server from function:
 addItem(id, rateId) {
      console.log('Adding item:', { id, rateId })
      if (this.cartItems[id]) {
        this.cartItems[id].count++
      } else {
        this.cartItems[id] = { count: 1, rateId }
      }
    },

in other cases all logs are identical
Also, i'm tryied reinstall pinia from legacy package and add in package.json vue:latest config.

cartStore is undefined for some reason, might be coming from cartStore.setCardsData(cardsData), or maybe this.cartStore.addItem(cardId, selectedRate.id)? Not sure but I recommend you to troubleshoot locally first. Do you use SSG? Build and run it locally to narrow down the issue.

@kissu no, i don't use ssg, i didn't see it in dependencies either. thanks for your answer, i'll check and come back with results

What do you use then? CSR/SSR? It's not a package btw, more of a rendering mode.

@kissu yes, I checked everything. In the file "nuxt.config.ts" I have no line "ssr: type" accordingly: ssr: true. But when I manually specified: "ssr: false" there were no changes on the server. Locally there are no errors or problems, but on the server we get the absence cartStore undefinded.
Would you be interested in taking a look at the whole project? I see that you want to help and maybe this will speed up the process. If yes, please write to my email and I will send you a link to the repository - nemercevroman@gmail.com

You need to be sure of what you use first, aka CSR/SSR or SSG. It is mostly easy to narrow down by looking if you build or generate your Nuxt app. As far as I know, Vercel does not support SSR (only SSG), hence this could be a quick and easy explanation why you're not able to reproduce the error locally (because you run it with a Node server while being in dev mode). If you do use SSG and use serve or alike for your preview, then it should also work on Vercel. You could also give Netlify a try to narrow it down. Overall, lots of assumptions haha, we need more local debugging overall.
